# Problema con Local Date en java

Tags: java

Buenas el problema que estoy teniendo con localDate es el siguiente , resulta que estoy modelando un sistema de facturación , para dicho sistema cree 2 clases que son factura e items, pero al querer crear una factura con el nombre del cliente y la fecha de dicha factura , no me deja hacerlo con el formato 00/00/0000 ya que me tira muchos errores , por lo tanto no se como se maneja localDate con el formato de la fecha.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Factura{

    private LocalDate fecha;
    private String nombreCliente;
    DateTimeFormatter formato = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    private long precioTotal;
    public static ArrayList<Item> lista = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public Factura(String nombreCliente,LocalDate fecha){
        this.nombreCliente=nombreCliente;
        this.fecha=fecha;

    }

    //metodos get y set

    public void ponerNombreCliente(String nombreCliente){
        this.nombreCliente=nombreCliente;
    }

    public void ponerFecha(LocalDate fecha){
        this.fecha=fecha;
    }

    public void ponerPrecioTotal(long precioTotal){
        this.precioTotal=precioTotal;
    }

    public long getPrecioTotal(){
        return precioTotal;
    }

    public LocalDate getFecha(){
        return fecha;
    }

    public String getNombreCliente(){
        return nombreCliente;
    }


}
```

Comment: Cuando te refieres a `"formato 00/00/0000"`: ¿Es que quieres crear un `LocalDate` con año cero, mes cero y dia cero?

Comment: No , a lo que me refiero es del estilo por ejemplo 03/09/2019 de esta manera

Comment: Te entiendo, Pero, en que momento le aplicas el formato, ese fragmento de codigo no lo colocaste.

Comment: claro ese es el tema no se como es el formato de localDate por defecto o si yo le tengo que agregar el formato que quiero

Comment: En tu clase factura ya tienes el `DateTimeFormatter formato`

Comment: si pero no se como aplicarlo al codigo para que funcione con ese formato

Comment: Te colocare una respuesta con dos opciones super sencillas.

Comment: Genial te agreadezco mucho , estoy muy trancada con este codigo, mil gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para no salir tanto del contexto de tu código, te dejo dos opciones super sencillas:

---

**Opción 1:** utiliza lo que ya tienes

```
LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.now();
Factura factura = new Factura("NombreCliente", fecha);

if(factura.getFecha() != null){
    System.out.println(factura.getFecha().format(factura.formato));
} else {
    System.out.println("00/00/0000");
    // no es necesario imprimir 00/00/0000, aquí puedes colocar
    // cualquier otra lógica en caso de que la fecha sea nula
}
```

Recuerda siempre validar si es distinto de nulo para evitar errores, ya que en tu método `ponerFecha` puedes pasar un nulo.

---

**Opción 2:** agregas un método adicional a la clase factura para obtener la fecha en una cadena. Siempre validando que la fecha no sea nula.

```
public String getStrFecha() {
    String srtFecha = "00/00/0000";

    LocalDate fechaTemp = this.getFecha();

    if(fechaTemp != null){
        srtFecha = fechaTemp.format(this.formato);
    }

    // no es necesario asignar 00/00/0000, aquí puedes colocar
    // cualquier otra lógica en caso de que la fecha sea nula,
    // claro siempre y cuando agregues un else.

    return srtFecha;
}
```

Y utilizas el método `getStrFecha` de esta forma:

```
LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.now();
Factura factura = new Factura("NombreCliente", fecha);

System.out.println(factura.getStrFecha());
```

---

Te aconsejo que utilices la opción 2, de esta forma no tienes que estar replicando o duplicando el `if` para la validación de la fecha por todos lados, si no que simplemente llamas al método `getStrFecha`.

Si te fijas la clase `LocalDate` tiene un método llamado `format` que es lo que te faltaba ya que el `DateTimeFormatter` lo tienes en tu clase factura.

Te dejo el enlace de la documentación del método [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-)